# Nothing happened when I re-enable my radio buttons with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Does someone can explain me why when I click on **'disable things'** radio button it works (first 2 radio buttons are disabled) but when I click back on **'enable things'** nothing happened?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/8822/

```
CMR convention: <input type="radio" name="cmrConvention" value="true" data-    bind="checkedRadioToBool: cmrConvention, disable: thirdPartyInsured() ? true : false">
<br/>
Out of CMR convention: <input type="radio" name="cmrConvention" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: cmrConvention, disable: thirdPartyInsured() ? true : false">
<br/>
- - - - - -
<br/>
Enable things: <input type="radio" name="thirdParty" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: thirdPartyInsured">
<br/>
Disable things: <input type="radio" name="thirdParty" value="true" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: thirdPartyInsured">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your computed the `newValue` will hold the `"true"` and `"false"` **strings** and not the `true` and `false` **boolean** values.

So you need to convert:

```
write: function (newValue) {
   var val = (newValue==='undefined') ? undefined : newValue;
   observable(val == 'true');
},
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/)

Your code worked for the first time because in JavaScript every nonempty string "evaluates" to `true` in logical expressions.

Comment: Thanks that's correct. One question: let's say possible values are true/false/undefined (like when backend is a database: when field in db is null). In this cas it don't work anymore. See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/1/

Comment: You need to set your `observable` to `null` when the newValue is `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/3/